# Android NDK converting YUV420 AIMAGE to RGB

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I'm working on streaming camera frames using NDK CAMERA2 API. the format of my AIMAGE_READER is YUV420;however I would like to convert it to RGB. I looked up some Java examples that do the same, but for some reason it doesn't work well and the image is distorted.

the frame resolution is 640X480.

can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here

```
void NativeCamera::previewImageCallback(void *context, AImageReader *reader)
{
    Log::Debug(TAG) << "previewImageCallback" << Log::Endl;
    AImage *previewImage = nullptr;
    auto status = AImageReader_acquireLatestImage(reader, &previewImage);

    if(status !=AMEDIA_OK)
    {
        return;
    }

    std::thread processor([=]()
                          {
                              uint8_t *dataY = nullptr;
                              uint8_t *dataU = nullptr;
                              uint8_t *dataV = nullptr;

                              int lenY = 0;
                              int lenU = 0;
                              int lenV = 0;


                              AImage_getPlaneData(previewImage, 0, (uint8_t**)&dataY, &lenY);
                              AImage_getPlaneData(previewImage, 1, (uint8_t**)&dataU, &lenU);
                              AImage_getPlaneData(previewImage, 2, (uint8_t**)&dataV, &lenV);

                              uchar buff[lenY+lenU+lenV];

                              memcpy(buff+0,dataY,lenY);
                              memcpy(buff+lenY,dataV,lenV);
                              memcpy(buff+lenY+lenV,dataU,lenU);

                              cv::Mat yuvMat(480+240,640,CV_8UC1,&buff);
                              cv::Mat rgbMat;
                              cv::cvtColor(yuvMat,rgbMat,cv::COLOR_YUV2RGB_NV21,3);

                               //colorBuffer defined elsewhere
                               memcpy((char*)colorBuffer,rgbMat.data,640*480*3);
```

Comment: An expected and actual image might be helpful

Comment: @AlanBirtles these are live frames from the camera, but I added a screenshot from my phone to show what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because YUV420p format has 6 bytes per 4 pixels, but RGB has 12 bytes per 4 pixel. So you have to repack your array first, cv::cvtColor - does not do it. Check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV) about YUV420p packing.